# Upgrading from 11.10 to 12.04

Tags: upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I upgrade from 10.04 or 11.10 to 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-from-10-04-or-11-10-to-12-04)

I am total newbie in ubuntu.Can I upgrade my ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04 without data losing?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume of comments about issues in upgrading to 12.04 seems pretty scary.

Personally I would make sure all your **data stays in the cloud** (Dropbox, UbuntuOne, etc) and is backed up on **external drives** (cheap now) and **CD/DVD** if possible. and when you are ready to go to 12.xx, do a clean install, install your key programs again and resync the data back in.

If you have a fair sized disk one good option (that I actually did) was to partition off another 100GB and just put it on that and have that be the new default first item to boot (which it will normally be with this install process) (actually a pretty good way to get several consequitive Ubuntu versions out of 1 machine !!!

Answer (score 0):

Dont Upgrade before 3 months. I also have 11.10 and Im planning to upgrade after 3 months.

Peoples are having lots of issues related to new 12.04. There is still less help available on net for newer problems and moreover you might lead to improper upgrade

Rule says a LTS version should upgrade to higher LTS verson. 11.10 is not the LTS version so upgrading it might lead to problems.

Im gonna wait for 12.10 or atleast 3 months. If you thinking of upgrading then It might be better to go for a complete reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

The upgrades are generally fairly safe, but if you're concerned about data loss - a reasonable concern - you should first do a backup.  That's true whether you upgrade now or whether you wait several months or a year.  Don't risk that which you can't afford to lose.

So whenever you do the upgrade, you should also realize that although nothing can be guaranteed to be problem-free, you should know that the process has been tested a lot.  A LOT!  Do what you can to be safe, read the directions (follow the link posted above by Jorge Castro) and comments, and then go ahead.  (In my case, I upgraded two computers from 11.10 to 12.04, one over the Internet and the other from the CD I downloaded and burned; I did it both ways just to learn the differences.)